# How Ubuntu initiates sleep on critically low battery?

Tags: suspend, power-management, hibernate

> **Little bit of context**: I have installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my Lenovo IdeaPad G710 and ever since then I am unable to wake it up from
>   sleeping/hibernation (it turns on, but screen remains either black (no
>   backlight) or freezes).
>
> I tried multiple ways to resolve the issue - switching to proprietary
>   drivers, initiating hibernation with systemctl commands, ..., almost
>   everything I Googled, but no luck. And yes, it worked on previous
>   versions.

Now I noticed that operation that my lap top does when it runs out of battery allows me to wake it up afterwards. Naturally I would like to know what exactly does Ubuntu call when it wants to put lap top to sleep because of battery level, so I could use it to put it to *recoverable* sleep.

**How does hibernating the machine because of critical battery level differ from systemctl hibernation in Ubuntu 17.04? And how do I initiate such hibernation manually?**

I do know how to code, so if you tell me where and what to look for in Ubuntu source code, I might be able to locate it.

---

As requsted by @MichalBay and based on information he provided, **EDIT**: I want to hibernate my laptop, but in a special manner. The same manner as system hibernates it when it runs out of battery. According to my observations it must differ from the way hibernation occurs when I do it via systemctl hibernate.

My HW specifications:

- **Graphics card**: GeForce 820M/PCIe/SSE2
- **Processor**: Intel® Core™ i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4

Comment: It differs as much as any suspending for any reason. Suspension and hibernation are quite different. Hibernation saves the session and shuts down entirely (needs at least the same amount of swap partition/file as RAM); suspension keeps the session alive in RAM and shuts down everything else. Suspension therefore uses energy and in a critically low battery, depending on how long it will stay suspended it may run out and then shutdown as normally. Please [edit] and describe exactly what you trying to do (suspend/hibernate) and while at it also post your hardware specifications.

Comment: @michaelBay: I updated the question. Thanks for your input so far.